# Component rendering as blank page when using hooks

Tags: reactjs

I've got the following component (sorry, pretty long):

```
const Help = () => {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (!user) {
      setDisplayName('')
      setEmail('')
      setSignedIn(false)
    } else {
      setDisplayName(user.displayName)
      setEmail(user.email)
      setSignedIn(true)
        }
      })
    })

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      axios.post("/api/submit/submitContact", {
        displayName: displayName,
        email: email,
        message: message
      })

      setStatus(true)
    }

    const renderForm = () => {
      return (
      <section className="help-section">
        <div className="help-container">

          { signedIn === true ?
            <DashboardReturn /> :
              <div className="dashboard-return-container">
                <div className="dashboard-return">
                  <a href="/">
                    <div className="dashboard-arrow">
                      <span className="arrow-span-1"></span>
                      <span className="arrow-span-2"></span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Return to homepage</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
          <form className="help-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <p className="help-form-heading">Get in touch</p>
            <label className="help-label">Name</label>
            <input className="help-input" type="text" name="displayName" value={displayName} onChange={(e) => setDisplayName(e.target.value)} />
            <label className="help-label">Email</label>
            <input className="help-input" type="text" name="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            <label className="help-label">How can we help?</label>
            <textarea className="help-textarea" type="text" name="message" value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />
            <button className="help-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
      )
    }

    const submitForm = () => {
      <section className="help-section">
        <div className="help-container">
          <a href="/">
            <h2 className="primary-logo">Lemio</h2>
          </a>
          <div className="help-success">
            <span className="help-success-span">
            <i className="fas fa-check-circle fa-3x"></i>
            <p>Thanks for getting in touch. We will get back to you as soon as possible. Return to your <a className="help-success-link" href="/dashboard">dashboard.</a></p>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    }

    return (
      <>
        {status === true ? renderForm() : submitForm() }
      </>
    )

  }
```

However, every time I try to render the page, it simply shows up as blank. I suspect it's a problem with my conditional statement, but it's not erroring, just showing up as blank.

Can anyone point out why my component isn't rendering? It feels like it's a really simple problem but I'm going a bit cross eyed.

Comment: Setting state inside the useEffect causing the issue, just change your useEffect function with conditional execution, useEffect(() => ..... your code ..... , [])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `submitForm` method. That function is not actually returning anything, hence nothing shows up when `state` is not set to `true`.

Try adding a `return` as you did in `renderForm` to return the whole JSX code, that should fix the problem.

Comment: This was right - I figured it out myself and tried it before you answered, just didn’t update my question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (!user) {
      setDisplayName('')
      setEmail('')
      setSignedIn(false)
    } else {
      setDisplayName(user.displayName)
      setEmail(user.email)
      setSignedIn(true)
    }
  })
}, [])
```

add proper dependency to `useEffect()`

```
return (
  <>
    {status !== true ? renderForm() : submitForm() }
  </>
)
```

and because your `status` is `false` initially, you should change the condition of render.

Answer (score 1):

Your component is rendering infinity, as you missing giving dependency with useEffect hook.

This may work Now

```js
const Help = () => {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (!user) {
      setDisplayName('')
      setEmail('')
      setSignedIn(false)
    } else {
      setDisplayName(user.displayName)
      setEmail(user.email)
      setSignedIn(true)
        }
      })
    }, [])

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      axios.post("/api/submit/submitContact", {
        displayName: displayName,
        email: email,
        message: message
      })

      setStatus(true)
    }

    const renderForm = () => {
      return (
      <section className="help-section">
        <div className="help-container">

          { signedIn === true ?
            <DashboardReturn /> :
              <div className="dashboard-return-container">
                <div className="dashboard-return">
                  <a href="/">
                    <div className="dashboard-arrow">
                      <span className="arrow-span-1"></span>
                      <span className="arrow-span-2"></span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Return to homepage</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
          <form className="help-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <p className="help-form-heading">Get in touch</p>
            <label className="help-label">Name</label>
            <input className="help-input" type="text" name="displayName" value={displayName} onChange={(e) => setDisplayName(e.target.value)} />
            <label className="help-label">Email</label>
            <input className="help-input" type="text" name="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            <label className="help-label">How can we help?</label>
            <textarea className="help-textarea" type="text" name="message" value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />
            <button className="help-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
      )
    }
```